# Can Cain&Able Crack SSL?

Tags: passwords, password-cracking

I have been messing around with Cain and Able and used APR on another computer (also mine) to get a hashed version of my username and password for my yahoo e-mail account, but I seem to be lost as to what to do next. I know that I need to crack the encryption on the password, but when I right-click on the hash and click on "Send to Cracker," it is not there when I go to the cracker part of the program. Therefore, I would like to know:

1. Is there a particular name for the type of encryption employed by SSL (I think it may be AES, but I am not sure)
2. Is Cain malfunctioning, or am I doing something wrong?
3. Are there any other programs I can access that can crack SSL? (With a dictionary attack)

I am not super picky, but I would prefer something with a GUI.

*I know it is simpler to use SSLStrip in conjunction with wireshark, but I am challenging myself to keep everything on Windows.

Answer (score 6):

Cain&Abel is a tool for cracking passwords. There is no password in SSL, so there is no password to crack. *That* is what you are doing wrong.

When a password is used "in SSL" it is actually transmitted *inside* a SSL tunnel, but the cryptography in SSL does not depend upon it in any way.

<sup>Note: there are some rare usages of SSL which include [passwords processing](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5054) but that's not what you observe, and SRP has been designed to be immune to offline password crackers anyway.</sup>